# Concatenate cell values if they have a similar value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I need to concatenate the city names that a person has been to into another cell but they have to be repeated every time the name of the person comes up. 
I tried using COUNTIF but couldn't get me anywhere.

I don't wanna use VB code; just formulas/functions. 
Any ideas?

[image]

[Here's the link to my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NRiapQwWEQVrfs1GCzCJZuAGP2aeO8tLfOZEjBLAhw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your sheet isn't shared at the moment  - can you change permissions plz? Also, are you looking for Excel and/or Google sheets solutions?

Comment: Just changed the permissions. 
I prefer Google Sheets.

Comment: Try something like: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B=B2)))`

Comment: Or something with `QUERY` possibly: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(QUERY(A:B,"SELECT A WHERE B = '"&B2&"'",-1)))`. It's not my forte but there may be a possibility to spill any of the above to the entire column.

Comment: Just perfect. Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @JvdV  - I had to tweak your formula a bit cause if B is empty, it doesn't work properly. Here's what I did: 

=IF(AC3 <>"",(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,AC:AC=AC3)))),"")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&",", B2:B&"♦"},
 "select max(Col1) where Col1 <> ',' group by Col1 pivot Col2")
 ,,99^99))), "♦")), 2, 0)), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: for some reason, when I drag your formula down to apply it to the whole column, it gives me a #REF! error.

Comment: its arrayformula eg. you are not supposed to drag it down - it auto calculates for all rows. just delete everything in C column and paste the formula into 2nd row. see your example sheet